# ec2 instace type: ami-e0efab88 has python installed but don't recognize it while installing libxml2-2.9.4

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, libxml2

I'm trying to install [libxml2-2.9.4](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz) (XML SUPPORT) on an ec2 instance with debian-wheezy-amd64-hvm-2015-01-28-ebs (ami-e0efab88)

`./configure` ran successfully

running `make` fails with an error: `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4/python'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4/python'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4/python'
CC       libxml.lo
libxml.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [libxml.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4/python'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4/python'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4/python'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/libxml2-2.9.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

running `python --version` indicates that `Python 2.7.3` is installed (BTW: how do i upgrade it to the latest version 2.7.10?)

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install all the required python development libraries, to be able to build it on your operating system.

Ubuntu / Debian

```
apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

CentOS / RedHat

```
yum install python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```